# execute "insert" raw sql query with on conflict "ignore" replacing bulk create in django rest framework

Tags: postgresql, django-rest-framework

This is the listserializer I am using to create multiple objects.

```
    class listSerializer(serializers.ListSerializer):
         def create(self, validated_data):
             objs = [klass(**item) for item in validated_data]
             return klass.objects.bulk_create(objs)
```

But bulk_create throws error for unique key error in postgres,So I need to execute this raw sql in same create function.I need help on translating validated_data to sql query.

```
    insert into table (count,value,type,mark,created_at) values 
       (3,32,2,162,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP),
       (4,33,1,162,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP),
       (3,33,1,162,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
       on CONFLICT do nothing
```

Comment: In newest development version of django, on_conflict='ignore' param is accepted by bulk_create which will solve the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class listSerializer(serializers.ListSerializer):   
 def create(self, validated_data):

        values = ''
        for data in validated_data:
            values+='('
            for item in data.values():
                values+=str(item)+','
            values+='CURRENT_TIMESTAMP),'


        cursor = connection.cursor()
        cursor.execute("insert into table (count,value,type,mark,created_at) values "+values[:-1]+"
   on conflict do nothing)
```